# javascript while loop not performing functions inside

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm a student and new so I'm sorry if my formatting is off.  I am having a problem with my while loop not executing the main functions inside the loop.  I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong.  I am making a tic tac toe game with a mario theme and a fair amount is working but my while loop runs through itself until it hits 'i = 9' and it seems to increase my marioCount to 9 as well but my goal was to have it alternate between classes when I click on a new box and that doesn't work.  I always get bowser.  Please help if possible and go easy on me, i'm a beginner.  Thanks in advance.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  var $quare = $('.square');
  var $brd = $('.board');
  var $tart = $('#start');
  var $bmario = $('#mario');
  var $bbowser = $('#bowser');
  var $cchar = $('#cchar');
  var clickedSquare = 0;
  var bowserCount = 0;
  marioCount = 0;

  $cchar.hide();
  $bmario.hide();
  $bbowser.hide();
  $brd.hide();

  $tart.on('click', function revealButton() {
    $bmario.show();
    $bbowser.show();
    $cchar.show();

  })

  $bmario.on('click', function() {
    $brd.show();
    $bbowser.hide();
    var i = 0
    while (i < 9) {

      if(marioCount % 2 === 0) {
        $quare.on('click', function() {
          $(this).addClass('smario clicked');
        })
      } else {
        $quare.on('click', function() {
          $(this).addClass('sbowser clicked');
        })
      }
      marioCount++
      i++
    }

  })
})
```

This is the HTML for my game

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Mario Tic Tac Toe</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/styles.css">
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="allBody">
      <div id="header">
        <div id="title">Tic Tac Toe</div>
      </div>
      <div id="startDiv">
        <button class="button" id="start">Start Game</button>
      </div>
      <div id="cchar">Pick Your Character</div>
      <div id="choose">
        <button class="button" id="mario"></button>
        <button class="button" id="bowser"></button>
      </div>
      <div class="board">
        <table class="tabl">
<!--           <tbody id="tbody"> -->
            <tr id="row1">
              <td class="square " id="square1"></td>
              <td class="square vmiddle" id="square2"></td>
              <td class="square" id="square3"></td>
            </tr>
            <tr id="row2">
              <td class="square hmiddle" id="square4"></td>
              <td class="square vmiddle hmiddle" id="square5"></td>
              <td class="square hmiddle" id="square6"></td>
            </tr>
            <tr id="row3">
              <td class="square" id="square7"></td>
              <td class="square vmiddle" id="square8"></td>
              <td class="square" id="square9"></td>
            </tr>
<!--           </tbody> -->
        </table>

        <!-- Game Here -->
      </div>
      <div id="info">...</div>
    </div>
    <script src="js/jquery-2.2.0.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/app.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Here's the CSS for the game

```
html {
  background: url(http://i1.kym-cdn.com/photos/images/original/000/939/881/cf4.png) no-repeat center center fixed;
  background-size: cover;
}
#title {
  text-align: center;
  color: yellow;
  font-size: 50px;
}

#startDiv {
  text-align: center;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

#choose {
  text-align: center;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

#mario {
  background: url("../images/Mario_super_cool.jpg");
  background-size: cover;
  height: 35px;
  width: 35px;
}

#bowser {
  background: url("../images/Bowser.jpg");
  background-size: cover;
  height: 35px;
  width: 35px;
}

#cchar {
  color: yellow;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 30px;
}

#start {
  text-align: center;
  margin: 0 auto;
  border-radius: 15px;
  color: yellow;
  font-size: 35px;
}

.smario {
  background: url("../images/Mario_super_cool.jpg");
  background-size: cover;
  height: 125px;
  width: 125px;
}

.sbowser {
  background: url("../images/Bowser.jpg");
  background-size: cover;
  height: 125px;
  width: 125px;
}

.board {
}

table {
  margin: auto;
  background: rgba(171, 39, 7, 0.5);
}



.square {
  float: left;
  font-family: 'Londrina Shadow', cursive;
  font-size: 50px;
  height: 125px;
  margin: 0px;
  text-align: center;
  vertical-align: middle;
  width: 125px;
}

.vmiddle {
  border-left: 5px solid yellow;
  border-right: 5px solid yellow;
  opacity: 1.4;
}

.hmiddle {
  border-top: 5px solid yellow;
  border-bottom: 5px solid yellow;
}
```

Comment: Please provide respective HTML & CSS.

Comment: marioCount % 2 === 0 change this to marioCount % 2 == 0.

Comment: ok, I'm going to add the html/css now

Comment: @Dr.Stitch - why? `===` is a valid operator.

Comment: The loop code doesn't make sense. On every iteration (so 9 times) it adds an *additional* click handler to *every* square, because `$quare` is a jquery object containing all your squares. If you want to process each square one at a time use `$quare.each()`.

Comment: when I replace $quare.on() with $quare.each()  I get the following error: ...........................                      jquery-2.2.0.min.js:2 Uncaught TypeError: b.call is not a functionn.extend.each @ jquery-2.2.0.min.js:2n.fn.n.each @ jquery-2.2.0.min.js:2(anonymous function) @ app.js:48n.event.dispatch @ jquery-2.2.0.min.js:3r.handle @ jquery-2.2.0.min.js:3

Comment: Sorry, I didn't mean that you could directly swap in `each()` where you did have `on()`. I was talking about fixing the logic, possibly by using `each()` instead of the while loop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need a loop here. Have a look at this code.

```
 $(".square").on("click", function () {
   if (!$(this).hasClass("clicked")) { // do something if this square hasn't been clicked
     if (marioCount % 2 === 0) {
       $(this).addClass("smario clicked");
     } else {
       $(this).addClass('sbowser clicked');
     }

     marioCount++;
  }
});
```

Comment: Thank you so much.  Brilliant

Answer (score 0):

Replace "< 9" with "< 10", since you are essentially saying "do this while i is 8 or less, but NOT 9", instead of what you want, "do this while i is 9 or less, but NOT 10".

Comment: Tic Tac Toe is normally 3 by 3, so he wants 9 and less.

Comment: @Dr.Stich, I know I should have not said "I assume".

Comment: I thought by saying whie( i < 9) it will continue looping until it hits 9 then it will stop because 9 > i.  Also, that's not the big problem I'm having.  It's that my while loop is looping without player interaction.